# Importing data from PDF to Database using PHP

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf, fpdf

Can we able to read the data from a **PDF** file to **PHP**.
We are able to read data from an excel or csv file, that can be directly imported to db using PHP.

Similarly is there any way to read data from a pdf file, and import it to database using PHP.

For Eg:

in a pdf file i have a table **employee details**
can we able to import that data to db using php..

Comment: Extracting data from generic PDF is difficult, sometimes impossible. Do your PDFs support text extraction at all (a smoke test: can you copy&paste using Adobe Reader)? If not, you'll have a hard time extracting anything from the PDF... And are they tagged? If not, you don't *have a table employee details* but merely some text chunks distributed fairly evenly in a given area and maybe some line or area color fill operations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try something like PDF Parser - http://www.pdfparser.org/

This will allow you to extract text from a PDF. From there, you can create a script to parse the extracted text and insert it into your database.